# Is it possible to have different layout elements inside CollapsingToolbarLayout?

Tags: android, android-toolbar, androiddesignsupport, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I'm trying to place `LinearLayout` which contains imageview buttons and other UI elements inside the `CollapsingToolbarLayout`, is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

[`CollapsingToolbarLayout`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CollapsingToolbarLayout.html) is a subclass of `FrameLayout` so it has the same behavior and in theory you can have `LinearLayout` as a child.

But usually `CollapsingToolbarLayout` should be a direct child of `AppBarLayout` and it should contain `Toolbar`. If you need an `ImageView` as a background you will have something like this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
... >
<android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
    ... >
    <ImageView
        .../>
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        ... />
</android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
```

If you need navigation buttons consider using `app:navigationIcon="@drawable/arrow_left"` inside `Toolbar`.